# adding tab to show metadata fields

Tags: gui-extensions

I want to add a new tab to PageView. This tab should show a custom metadata schema I create. Also, should persist the data on save of page.
Can anyone give some pointers?

Comment: Seems you want to show the content added to the metadata of the page in a different tab, not showing the schema, right? Could you give a more detailed explanation of the scenario?

Comment: I agree with Bart.  Also, you will lose the additional advantage of the Metadata being published to the Broker automatically, and if your Metadata uses Component Links, they will not show up in WhereUsed if you use ApplicationData.  An additional tab would normally be used to show editable data from an external system or read-only data from Tridion.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Yes @Miguel, alternatively we can think of showing the metadata schema in a separate tab instead of showing in General tab.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way for you to store additional custom metadata of a Page, since a Page can only have a single metadata Schema and whatever metadata is set in there will be persisted in the CMS database.

Maybe I'm saying "no" too soon, what you could consider is using Application Data for storing your additional metadata, that is possible and would be doable in a UI extension.

But my main question would be, why do you need additional metadata on a Page, can't you just use a metadata Schema on the Page and have the content added under the General tab of the Page view? Why make something complex (UI extension, adding additional tab, storing in app data), if it is already available to you...

### update

If your requirements are driven because you have too many metadata fields, then I would still leave them in the single metadata Schema and attach that to your Page (then you don;t need to worry about storage). What you can consider is adding a UI extension which will show the metadata in a separate tab, but I would actually look at the data and see if it can be structured itself.

You mention you have 20+ fields, are all of those unique to the Page, or is there data in there which you set for each Page the same? In that case, you could extract those parts into a separate Schema (make it a Component Schema) and replace that bunch of fields with a single Component Link.

Comment: Thanks Bart for your suggestion. We might have 20+ fields in the metadata for the page, hence would like to separate them into another custom metadata schema and show it in another tab. Or is there a way to show the metadata in a separate tab instead of General tab?